# How to add NewForm.aspx to directly into my page in share point 2013 online

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, custom-lists

I have a custom list in my Share point 2013 site. I need to add the NewForm.aspx of the custom list directly to one of my page , so that users when visit the page, they will be presented with the form.
Once that form is submitted, I need to show a thank you message to the user.
PS: I dont have access to the Share point designer so, looking for a solution in Sharepoint online only.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to modify the link you're using to direct users to the form. Send them directly to your form, but modify the default URL so that they are redirected to a thank you page on submit.

Example: http://yoursite/org/hr/Lists/contactUs/Item/newifs.aspx?List=b5b9e317%2D4776%2D4827%2D9d29%2Db4dedc59a75a**&Source=http://yoursite/pages/thanks.aspx**

Hope that helps.